# how to distribute and sell python desktop apps?

Tags: python, database, tkinter

I have created a Tkinter App and i want to sell and distribute it, but i was wondering how do desktop programmers prevent the customer from reselling the App multiply times if there is no Cloud Database to verify the Login process and prevent multi login actions, etc? Especially a Tkinter App, how does it work?

I know about using `pyinstaller`, but this is not the issue as it allows using the app by anyone.

Comment: Maybe look into online marketplace platforms like Gumroad or Humble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are ways.

The first way is to use itch.io, its easy and simple to distribute paid software.

The alternative way is you can build a website that the person can download when they pay using backend django, but i would assume this is too advanced.

There are plenty more other platforms and tools to sell programs, and feel free to use others. ive used itch.io for my 1 dollar black jack game and its worked pretty well, so i hope you find this useful!